# vector but not matrix norm

Tags: normed-spaces, matrix-analysis

Is there a norm $\|\cdot\|_\sharp$ on $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ for which $\| I\|_\sharp=1$ and there is a matrix $M$ such that $\|M^2\|_\sharp>\|M\|_\sharp^2$?

Comment: Pick any norm and scale it.

Comment: Sure, I forget to add $\| I\|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an example for $n=3$:

For positive $N$ to be chosen later, define
$$
\lVert A\rVert_{\sharp} := \sup_{i,j}\lvert A_{ij}\rvert + N \lvert A_{13}\rvert
$$
and let
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $\lVert M\rVert_{\sharp}=1$ and $\lVert M^2\rVert_{\sharp}=N+1$.  Now choose $N$ massive.